# Reformatting Pandas DataFrame with multiple date and value columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the format:

```
data = [
    ["true","penguin","canary","01/01/2000","3","01/02/2000","10","01/03/2000", "4", "01/04/2000","181"],
    ["false","tiger","prod","02/01/2000","9","02/02/2000","101","02/03/2000","43","02/04/2000","11"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
       "status","team","env","date_1","value_1","date_2","value_2","date_3","value_3","date_4","value_4"])
```

And I'd like to get it into the format:

| Status | team | env | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | penguin | canary | 01/01/2000 | 3 |
| false | tiger | prod | 02/01/2000 | 9 |
| true | penguin | canary | 01/02/2000 | 10 |
| false | tiger | prod | 02/02/2000 | 101 |
| true | penguin | canary | 01/03/2000 | 4 |
| false | tiger | prod | 02/03/2000 | 43 |
| true | penguin | canary | 01/04/2000 | 181 |
| false | tiger | prod | 02/04/2000 | 11 |

I've been trying to use melt() and stack() and unstack(), but the closest I've come has been:
`df = df.melt(id_vars=["status", "team", "env"])` 
Which leaves me with a variable column containing 'date_1','date_1','value_1','value_1' and a value column with their respective values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```py
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, ['date_', 'value_'], i=['status','team','env'], j='idx')
       .rename(columns={'date_': 'Date', 'value_': 'Value'})
       .reset_index()
       .drop(columns='idx'))
```

```
print(out)

  status     team     env        Date Value
0   true  penguin  canary  01/01/2000     3
1   true  penguin  canary  01/02/2000    10
2   true  penguin  canary  01/03/2000     4
3   true  penguin  canary  01/04/2000   181
4  false    tiger    prod  02/01/2000     9
5  false    tiger    prod  02/02/2000   101
6  false    tiger    prod  02/03/2000    43
7  false    tiger    prod  02/04/2000    11
```

Comment: Amazing! I had given up on wide_to_long but wasn't including the '_' and didn't realize you could reference the index with idx. I was doing a whole other step of setting up an index column. Thank yo so much.